# How to setup a default current_user for demo purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've set a fake user to demo my app.  The idea is that visitors, who won't be signing in, should still be able to see all the functionality that a real user would have.  When a non-logged-in visitor hits the site, the app will sign in the demo user and visitors will see fake data belonging to this demo user.

With this goal in mind, I setup my application controller like this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def demo_user
    @demo_user ||= User.find_by_email("demo@example.com")
  end

  protected
    def set_current_user
      if current_user.nil?
        sign_in(demo_user)
      end
    end
end
```

My problem is that I accidentally made it impossible for real users to sign in.  Anytime a real user presses the "sign in" link, they're told that they're already signed in (as the demo user).

So clearly, what I've done is nowhere close to a "best practice."  What would a smart programmer do in this situation?  How do I keep my nifty automatically signed in demo user but still leave the door open to real users to sign in?

Comment: Why do you need a fake user then? What is the content that the non-signed in users cannot see and that signed in users can? And how are you stopping the non-signed in users not to see it?
You've also made it easy for a non-signed in user to do whatever a real user can (i.e. create posts, delete posts etc.).

Comment: how about to add another button with sign in demo user, so you wont have to mess with before filters?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an `:except` to your `:before_filter` so that it doesn't run on the sign_in action, whatever it may be.  Assuming you're using devise, that would be `SessionsController#new`, so it would look like:

```
before_filter :set_current_user, :except => :new
```

Note that this will skip the filter for all 'new' actions, so a more targetted way of doing it would be (again, assuming you are using Devise) to create a custom `SessionsController` which inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` and leave it blank except for:

```
skip_before_filter :set_current_user, :only => [:new, create]
```

Comment: With Devise you may need to target both `:new` and `:create`

Comment: This definitely makes sense.  But I think there might be something more that I need to do. I can't even get the signon page.  When I click the link for the new session, I still get the message that I'm already signed in.  I restarted my server, as a precaution, but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: You could add a `before_filter` for the `sessions_controller#new` action that logs out the current user.

Comment: have you set devise to use your custom controller in your config/routes.rb? You'd need to have something like this: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "devise/sessions" }` and then create your custom controller in `app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`

Comment: The controller is setup correctly.  I'm really confused as to why I'm having all this trouble.  The skip_before_filter seems like it'd work perfecty.

Comment: Reed G. Law, I may taking your advice and adding a before_filter in the sessions_controller if I can't figure out why I can't get the skip_before_filter to work properly.

Comment: That would probably work, an alternative might be to add a skip_before_filter to your homepage or root action as well; seeing as anybody who hits _any_ part of your site except the sign in page is logged in automatically, the skip before filter doesn't do any good unless the sign in page is the default route when visiting your site.

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_current_user` function is in a `before_filter` which means it runs once for every request. The `current_user` will be `nil` the first time anyone visits and so they will be signed in as the demo user. You can skip the `before_filter` for your `sessions_controller#create` action (or whatever it's called in your app. For example, if you are using Devise:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :set_current_user, :only => :create
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with.  I started off with Omnikron's solution, but I needed a little more.

This post helped: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/plataformatec-devise/0WylcwjSAJY/ITDF6kFjJvwJ.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :set_current_user, only: [:new, :create]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:new, :create]

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      sign_out current_user
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      super
    end
  end
 end
```